# Errno 36: File name too long error parsing python XML

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have an XML file I am trying to parse and access one root of: `DonorAdvisedFundInd` which I shouldn't have a problem with but when I'm trying to parse the XML file I get an error message saying:

> [Errno 36] File name too long:`

Here's the code I'm currently using: I cut off most of it so it's easier to see the problem. The error is occurring on the parse line.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import requests
 
xml_data = requests.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201903199349320465_public.xml").content
xtree = et.parse(xml_data)
```

Now the reason I'm so confused is if you open that link, the XML file really isn't all that long. It should be able to be parsed. I'm using IBM Watson Studio's online compiler if it makes any difference.

I'd appreciate any insight or feedback anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fromstring`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import requests
 
xml_data = requests.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201903199349320465_public.xml").content
xtree = et.fromstring(xml_data)
```

**Update** *(for finding the specific element)*:

```py
for i in xtree.findall(".//"):
    if 'DonorAdvisedFundInd' in i.tag:
        print(i.tag, i.attrib, i.text)
```

Another way would have been using this `xmltodict` lib like this:

```py
result = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
result['Return']['ReturnData']['IRS990']['DonorAdvisedFundInd']
```

Comment: This does not return an error, but the output is the following: `<Element '{http://www.irs.gov/efile}Return' at 0x7f68e94ab318>`       How do I access one element of it now? Because I get an error message when I try to getroot()

Comment: ```for child in xtree:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)```

Comment: This only returns the following: `{http://www.irs.gov/efile}ReturnHeader {'binaryAttachmentCnt': '0'}
{http://www.irs.gov/efile}ReturnData {'documentCnt': '4'}` if it makes it any easier, I'm trying to access the value of <DonorAdvisedFundInd>. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This looks great! Thanks so much! I have one question though. So I used the first version of your code with the for loop and here's my output: `{http://www.irs.gov/efile}DonorAdvisedFundInd {'referenceDocumentId': 'RetDoc1040000001'}`     so it's definitely accessing the file. However it does not return the 0 value, which is what I really want. How can I get it to return this? Because I will be analyzing millions of documents and some of them will have 0s and some will have 1s.

Comment: Use this `print(i.tag, i.attrib, i.text)`